# How can I stop OS X from switching Spaces when the mouse cursor is at the edge of the screen?

Tags: macos, mac, spaces

Mac OS X [Spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_%28software%29) change when I hold the mouse at the edge of the screen. Is there an application or 'defaults' command to disable this?

[Warp](http://www.ksuther.com/warp/) looks like it might help, but hasn't changed the behavior for me, even though I tried turning it off, or setting a modifier key.

Comment: The answers given are interesting, but do not explain why the mouse would switch workspaces when you are not dragging a window. I added a different answer that I think answers this question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found a solution. The following sets the delay to 1 minute.

`defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-edge-delay -float 60 && killall Dock`

source: [Leopard: Lower the window drag delay between spaces](http://kaspers.freeflux.net/blog/archive/2007/10/19/leopard-lower-the-space-drag-delay.html)

Comment: The link is dead.  However, the Wayback Machine archived the article (yay!): https://web.archive.org/web/20170216132739/http://kaspers.freeflux.net:80/blog/archive/2007/10/19/leopard-lower-the-space-drag-delay.html

Answer (score 12):

OS X - Snow Leopard seems to have two states when it comes to the switching behavior. Dragging a window or not dragging a window. If you are not dragging a window, it ignores your mouse hovering at a side. This makes sense, or the dock and hot corners would be very hard to use. When you are dragging a window, it auto-switches workspaces if you hang around at a side. This also makes sense.

Sometimes though, it seems to get confused about if you're dragging a window or not. When this happens, even if you aren't dragging a window, it still flips workspaces if you hover the mouse on a side, thereby making the dock and hot corners very hard to use.

In order to reset this state, I figured out that you can pick up a window, drag it around a bit, then let go. This seems to reset its "you're currently dragging a window" state with respect to workspace switching.

Comment: I don't think switching with mouse without dragging is a bug. It is another method to switch from one space to another, which is often done without moving an app.

Comment: @mankoff - Then why does it switch when I stay in a hot corner or try to access the dock? That doesn't seem like correct behavior to me.

Comment: Don't know why, but this works and seems to address this bug (yes, it's most definitely a BUG!).

Comment: This was the case for me using Yosemite. I was using synergy to share keyboard/mouse between computers and when my mouse went to the other desktop and the cursor was at the edge of the screen, it started switching workspaces. Click-dragging a window around for a second seems to have fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

It only switches when you're actively dragging something and linger on the edge of the screen for several seconds. Simply hovering shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Agreed. mankoff, can you detail what is done a bit more before Spaces changes?

Comment: mine seems to switch after about 1 second, which is too quickly. I never want it to switch this way at all. If I could set it to 10 seconds that would probably be OK.

I think the problem occurs like this: I drag something to the top (or side) and then spend 1 or 2 seconds fine-tune positioning it to the left/right (if at top) or up/down (if on side). During this fine-tune positioning, I keep it against the top (or side) and the switch occurs.

I just want this behavior to go away.

Comment: Sorry for the poorly worded original question. Hover was the wrong word. I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Warp successfully to do that.  I've checked "Enable Warp" and "Click screen edge to Warp".  When I touch an edge, I get a small window surrounding the cursor that either shows a tiny view of the adjacent space and its windows, or says "No windows" -- is that what you're seeing?  At that point, clicking will change spaces, or you can back away from the edge to remain in the same space.

Edit:  Oops - I have to backtrack. My answer applies to just the mouse cursor, not to dragging a window.  I see the same behavior you describe if I drag a window to the edge and hover there holding it: Spaces will switch repeatedly until I back the cursor off of the edge.

Comment: Actually for some reason warp has no effect on my computer. I've logged out and back in but not rebooted, but I don't see why it would need a reboot.

I cannot get the behavior you have. The time slider doesn't have an effect (it is always about a second). Modifier keys don't do anything. Etc. Which is fine, I think, because I don't actually want to warp...